# Error while Trying to install Asp.net Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Currently i have Installed Visual Studio 2015 Community
version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.
While Trying to install "**DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2**"
Getting Error : "Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be completely installed…"
I Repaired visual studio many time but still getting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft announced an update [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/release-notes.md#8112016-tooling-update-for-net-core-100---vs-2015-tooling-preview-2) on 8/11/2016 which resolves this issue and a few others, it is also a cumulative update.  The new installer can be found [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817245).  You can also use the `SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1` argument on the command-line with the old installer to work around the issue as well.